# Append SourceIp To AWS Step Function Input Via Mapping Template

Tags: mapping, aws-api-gateway

I have been trying to add sourceIp to my step functions input via mapping templates before it is triggered.

Basically,

Before:

```
{
"input": "{\"uuid\":\"12345\",\"domain\":\"stackoverflow.com\"}",
"stateMachineArn": "arn:aws:states:us-east-1:xxx:xxxx"
}
```

After:

```
{
"input": "{\"uuid\":\"12345\",\"domain\":\"stackoverflow.com\,\"sourceIp\":\"0.0.0.0\"}",
"stateMachineArn": "arn:aws:states:us-east-1:xxx:xxxx"
}
```

I have tried a slew of mapping template configurations, however this is the closest I can get, which chatGPT insists should work

```
#set($elem = $util.parseJson($input.json('$')))
#set($source = $context.identity.sourceIp)

#set($inputValue = $elem.get("input"))
#set($updatedInput = $util.parseJson($inputValue).put("source", $source))
#set($updatedInputString = $util.escapeJavaScript($util.toJson($updatedInput)))

{
  "input": "$updatedInputString",
  "stateMachineArn": "$elem.stateMachineArn"
}
```

Which results in this:

```
 {
   "input": "",
   "stateMachineArn": "arn:aws:states:us-east-1:xxx:xxxx"
 }
```

I'm at my wits end with this, and would appreciate any input.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the prettiest, but it works in my case. Hope it helps others!

```
#set($elem = $util.parseJson($input.json('$')))
#set($secondElem = $util.parseJson($elem.input))
#set($sourceIp = $context.identity.sourceIp)


{
  "input": "{\"uuid\": \"$secondElem.uuid\",\"domain\": \"$secondElem.domain\",\"source\": \"$sourceIp\"}",
  "stateMachineArn": "$elem.stateMachineArn"
}
```